# Java validate date in yyyyMMddHHmmss

Tags: java, java-7, java.util.date

i want to validate the given date format as yyyyMMddHHmmss in java.

Conditions:

1. It should meet the format yyyyMMddHHmmss.
2. It should validate the current date.
3. It should validate hours which can be +3 hours or -3 hours variance with the current hour.

If all three conditions are met, the Java method should return true.

My current code only validates the yyyyMMddHHmmss format.

My current code

```
public class SO31132861 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    df.setLenient(false);

    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160630231110"));
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228231100"));
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231100"));

    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "21000229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2100
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160631231110")); // 31st Jun invalid day
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231160")); // Second > 59
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2015
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228241100")); // Hour > 23

}

private static Boolean tryParse(DateFormat df, String s) {
    Boolean valid=false;
    try {
        Date d= df.parse(s);
        valid=true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
         valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I'm seeing that you've posted several requirements, but I don't see any focused and specific questions just yet. What have you done? Where exactly are you stuck? Please have a look at the [help] for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: The first two could be achieved with a `SimpleDateFormat`, the third would probably require maybe a `LocalDateTime` from either Java 8's Time API or JodaTime

Comment: You could also compare dates by `date.getTime()` on millisecond level (as long). But I'd also recommend trying it by yourself first.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "It should validate the current date" - do you mean the only valid date is the current date? It seems odd to include the date on the input, to be honest...

Comment: Additionally, you need to specify which time zone these validation rules are meant to work in. And if it's currently 1am, does the "3 hours before" rule mean that yesterday's date *is* valid after all?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two other dates, three hours ahead and three hours behind, for comparison.  Then make sure the date that you are parsing is between those two boundaries using `compareTo()`.

You really shouldn't put numbers in your class names, but that's a style issue that's irrelevant to the answer.

```
public class SO31132861 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    df.setLenient(false);

    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160630231110"));
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228231100"));
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231100"));

    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "21000229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2100
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160631231110")); // 31st Jun invalid day
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20160229231160")); // Second > 59
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150229231100")); // 29th Feb on non-leap year 2015
    System.out.println(tryParse(df, "20150228241100")); // Hour > 23

}

private static Boolean tryParse(DateFormat df, String s) {
    Boolean valid=false;
    try {
        Date threeHoursBefore = new Date();
        threeHoursBefore.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - (3*60*60*1000));

        Date threeHoursAfter = new Date();
        threeHoursAfter.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() + (3*60*60*1000));

        Date dateToParse= df.parse(s);

        valid=dateToParse.compareTo(threeHoursBefore) > 0 && dateToParse.compareTo(threeHoursAfter) < 0;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
         valid=false;
    }
    return valid;
}
}
```